# How do I dynamically set the forecolour of my column data based on the value when exporting excel using EPPLUS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, epplus

I have a set of codes to export grid view data to excel using EPPLUS. I am able to export the data to EPPLUS. But how do I export the colour of the font to excel as well? Can I set the dynamic coding for the font colour if ..... colour = green if ..... colour = red?

Thus I will need column4 to be coloured as well according to the value I set.

The below codes is how I set dynamically for gridview:

```
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[16];
                int Num = int.Parse(cell.Text);
                if (Num >= 1&& Num <= 11)
                {
                    cell.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                if (Num >= 12&& Num <= 39)
                {
                    cell.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                }
..........

        }
```

The codes for my export:

```
  protected void EXPORT_BUTTON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

            ExcelWorksheet Grid = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ORSA ASSESSMENTS"); 


            DataTable Gridview1 = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < Gridview1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Gridview1.Columns.Add("column" + i.ToString());
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = Gridview1.NewRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < Gridview1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    row.Cells[j].Text = row.Cells[j].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
                    dr["column" + j.ToString()] = row.Cells[j].Text;

                }

                Gridview1.Rows.Add(dr);
            }


            Grid.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(Gridview1, true);

            using (ExcelRange rng = Grid.Cells["A1:Z1"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            }

            Grid.Cells[ORSA.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();



                var FolderPath = ServerName + DirectoryLocation + DirectoryFolder + ExportsFolder;
                var filename = ExcelName + @"_"  + ".xlsx";
                var filepath = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(FolderPath, filename));

                Response.Clear();
                package.SaveAs(filepath);
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ";");
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
                Response.TransmitFile(filepath.FullName);
                Response.End();

        }
```

Thus how can I do in my export codes so that I can export or set the forecolour dynamically upon exporting?

thanks

Comment: The answer is you can't. You must do the looping on the column for cell coloring.. There is no easy ways for this.

Comment: @Nic Do you have any idea how I can loop this?

Comment: Check the answer below

Comment: @Nic, Can I seek your kind help to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559513/how-do-i-select-the-top-1-results-of-the-if-the-same-identifier-exist-sql-serve thanks

Comment: Sorry i'm not good in SQL... Can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line

```
Grid.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(Gridview1, true);
```

Do a looping to loop the count of your `DataTable`

Example

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Create Column
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add("column" + i, typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4);

        GenerateExcel(dt);
    }
}

private void GenerateExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    using (ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        int num = 0;
        string value = string.Empty;

        ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

        // Get Your DataTable Count
        int count = dt.Rows.Count;
        int countCol = dt.Columns.Count;
        bool isHeader = true;


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {                
            // Set Border
            for (int j = 1; j <= countCol; j++)
            {
                // Set Border For Header. Run once only
                if (isHeader) ws.Cells[1, j].Style.Border.BorderAround(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thin, System.Drawing.Color.Black);

                ws.Cells[2 + i, j].Style.Border.BorderAround(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thin, System.Drawing.Color.Black);
            }

            // Set to false
            isHeader = false;

            // Cells 2 + i == Rows, Wondering start with 2 because your 1st rows is Title so 2 is the value
            // Cells 2 == Column make sure your column is fix
            value = ws.Cells[2 + i, 2].Value + ""; // You can use .ToString() if u sure is not null

            // Parse
            int.TryParse(value, out num);

            // Check
            if (num >= 1 && num <= 11)
                ws.Cells[2 + i, 2].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
            else if (num >= 12 && num <= 39)
                ws.Cells[2 + i, 2].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
        }

        pkg.SaveAs(new FileInfo("C:\\Test.xlsx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nic, I have updated my codes accordingly but there seems to be no changes in the exported excel file.

Comment: @JamesBoer can you update your question regarding the code you updated ? Without code i don't know what error you encounter..

Comment: HI @Nic, Do you know how to remove the banded rows in tablestyles with EPPLUS? currently im using your method to add tablestyle which comes with filter buttons, banded rows and header rows. How can I add tablesstyle without banded rows in my codes?

Comment: @JamesBoer if you are using the tablestyle then you can't but you can programmatically remove it after u load the `DataTable` in the `Excel `

Comment: can you please teach me how can I progratmatically remove the banded rows please? if possible filter buttons as well? thanks much. @Nic

Comment: @JamesBoer Updated the code no longer using table style but you want border. `TableStyle` will automatic create `Filter` and `header/alternate` row color by the `TableStyle` you selected

Comment: thanks a lot. Might need your help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433029/how-do-i-set-my-default-checked-checkbox-on-pageload-for-my-latest-date-in-check