# How do I select the top 1 results of the if the same identifier exist? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, identifier

I have a data table in sql server 2008 that I would like to select the top 1 out of each identifier:

The results shld looks like this during before and after:

[image]

Thus it should only select the 1st results if the same identifier do exist. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi all please take note that I actually have other columns as well. thus it affects the identifier to be distinct, thus I hope to use get it like using top 1 etc

Comment: what in the other columns determines the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just distinct them:

```
select distinct [primary identifier] from tablename
```

Or by grouping:

```
select [primary identifier] from tablename group by [primary identifier]
```

If more columns exist you can rank rows with window function:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by [primary identifier] order by (select null)) rn from tablename)
 select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Change `order by (select null)` to appropriate ordering column.

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct [Primary Identifier] from tbl
```

If you have entire records (other columns) instead of that single column, you can row number them and choose one.

```
select {list of columns}
  from
  (
select *, rn = row_number over (partition by [Primary Identifier]
                                order by 1/0)
  from tbl
  ) X
 where rn = 1;
```

`order by 1/0` is arbitrary.  If you need to choose a specific one from the "duplicates", for example the highest `cost`, you order by `cost descending`, i.e.

```
                               (partition by [Primary Identifier]
                                order by [cost] descending)
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this will be an appropriate solution to your need-

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Primary Identifier] ORDER BY [sort   columns]) AS rowid
 FROM [table]
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rowid = 1
```